Get kubernetes pod lastTransitionTime
Looking at Pod Lifecycle doc, I see a status section with eg:
status:
  conditions:
    - type: Ready                              # a built in PodCondition
      status: "False"
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z

for a pod. How do I view this output using kubectl? When I run kubectl describe pod podname, I get output like:
Name: podname
...
Status:           Running
...
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True 
  Initialized                 True 
  Ready                       True 
  ContainersReady             True 
  PodScheduled                True

However this output doesn't look like the example documented in pod readiness, and is notably missing the lastProbeTime & lastTransitionTime that I'm after. What command should I be running to get this information?

The spec talked about in Pod lifecycle can be retrieved with kubectl get pod pod-name -o json. kubectl get pod pod-name just returns a summary, and the full json information can be achieved with -o json.
A more succinct answer can use jsonpath ie something like
kubectl get pod pod-name -o jsonpath='{.status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].lastTransitionTime} to parse through above json & find specifically the time I'm looking for.

-o yaml will look even more like what's in the documentation.


Kubectl get pod pod-name -o yaml

will give you the output you need.
